# Curve fitting with broken power law in Python

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting

Im trying to follow and re-use a piece of code (with my own data) suggested by someone named @ThePredator (I couldn't comment on that thread since I don't currently have the required reputation of 50). The full code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np # This is the Numpy module
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit # The module that contains the curve_fit routine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # This is the matplotlib module which we use for plotting the result

""" Below is the function that returns the final y according to the conditions """

def fitfunc(x,a1,a2):
    y1 = (x**(a1) )[x<xc]
    y2 = (x**(a1-a2) )[x>xc]
    y3 = (0)[x==xc]
    y = np.concatenate((y1,y2,y3))
    return y

x = array([0.001, 0.524, 0.625, 0.670, 0.790, 0.910, 1.240, 1.640, 2.180, 35460])
y = array([7.435e-13, 3.374e-14, 1.953e-14, 3.848e-14, 4.510e-14, 5.702e-14, 5.176e-14, 6.0e-14,3.049e-14,1.12e-17])

""" In the above code, we have imported 3 modules, namely Numpy, Scipy and  matplotlib """

popt,pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc,x,y,p0=(10.0,1.0)) #here we provide random initial parameters a1,a2

a1 = popt[0] 
a2 = popt[1]
residuals = y - fitfunc(x,a1,a2)
chi-sq = sum( (residuals**2)/fitfunc(x,a1,a2) ) # This is the chi-square for your fitted curve

""" Now if you need to plot, perform the code below """
curvey = fitfunc(x,a1,a2) # This is your y axis fit-line

plt.plot(x, curvey, 'red', label='The best-fit line')
plt.scatter(x,y, c='b',label='The data points')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Im having some problem running this code and the errors I get are as follows:

y3 = (0)[x==xc]

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

and also:

xc is undefined

I don't see anything missing in the code (xc shouldn't have to be defined?).

Could the author (@ThePredator) or someone else having knowledge about this please help me identify what i haven't seen.

- New version of code:

  ```
  import numpy as np # This is the Numpy module
  from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

  def fitfunc(x, a1, a2, xc):
      if x.all() < xc:
        y = x**a1
      elif x.all() > xc:
        y = x**(a1 - a2) * x**a2
      else:
        y = 0
      return y

  xc = 2
  x = np.array([0.001, 0.524, 0.625, 0.670, 0.790, 0.910, 1.240, 1.640, 2.180, 35460])
  y = np.array([7.435e-13, 3.374e-14, 1.953e-14, 3.848e-14, 4.510e-14, 5.702e-14, 5.176e-14, 6.0e-14,3.049e-14,1.12e-17])

  popt,pcov = curve_fit(fitfunc,x,y,p0=(1.0,1.0)) 

  a1 = popt[0] 
  a2 = popt[1]
  residuals = y - fitfunc(x, a1, a2, xc)
  chisq = sum((residuals**2)/fitfunc(x, a1, a2, xc)) 
  curvey = [fitfunc(val, a1, a2, xc) for val in x] #  y-axis fit-line

  plt.plot(x, curvey, 'red', label='The best-fit line')
  plt.scatter(x,y, c='b',label='The data points')
  plt.legend(loc='best')
  plt.show()
  ```

Comment: You do need to define `xc` if you make reference to its value (as you do in the comparisons used in `fitfunc`.) The line `y3 = (0)[x==xc]` is not valid Python syntax: `(0)` is an integer object which cannot be indexed with NumPy-style boolean indexing, `[x==xc]`.

Comment: `chi-sq` is an invalid variable name, use underscore instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. Understood the mistakes in the line y3 = (0)[x==xc], chi-sq and the array. About the variable xc, should I define it with an initial value, which is supplied to the fitting function?

Comment: In the comments to the answer you have changed your code, but haven't updated it in your question. You now claim to have another, unspecified error in the resulting code. I still can't figure out how you got from @ThePredator's obvious `if(x==xc)  y = 0;` to `y3 = (0)[x==xc]`.

Comment: @ThePredator python code already has `y3 = (0)[x==xc]` its actually the original question in which the asker mentioned `if(x==xc) y = 0;` as a piece of Origin code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors/typos in your code.

1) You cannot use `-` in your variable names in Python (chi-square should be `chi_square` for example)

2) You should `from numpy import array` or replace `array` with `np.array`. Currently the name `array` is not defined.

3) `xc` is not defined, you should set it before calling `fitfunc()`.

4) `y3 = (0)[x==xc]` is not valid, should be (I think) `y3 = np.zeros(len(x))[x==xc]` or `y3 = np.zeros(np.sum(x==xc))`

Your use of fit_function() is wrong, because it changes the order of the images. What you want is:

```
def fit_function(x, a1, a2, xc):
    if x < xc:
        y = x**a1
    elif x > xc:
        y = x**(a1 - a2) * x**a2
    else:
        y = 0
    return y
xc = 2 #or any value you want
curvey = [fit_function(val, a1, a2, xc) for val in x]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @M. Massias. Heres the link to the original thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153048/implementing-a-broken-power-law-as-a-fitting-function-in-origin/

Comment: Ok now it complains about `y = np.concatenate((y1,y2,y3))` that its invalid syntax.

Comment: Got rid of the all the mistakes. the line 'y3 = np.zeros(np.sum(x==xc))' worked whereas 'y3 = np.zeros(len(x)[x==xc]' did not. So the code is now running without errors, but its not actually fitting the data with a broken power law as expected. The best fit line is a line at y = 0. Not sure how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: Ok I'll give it some thought to try and see whats going wrong or what is it that I'm not getting. It would be great if you could help when it is convenient for you.

Comment: trying it now. There seems to be problems. I'm trying a few things. Will update with the progress....

Comment: @Aqib keep me posted about your progress

Comment: sorry I got drifted to something else. Got back to broken law now and Im still try to use the broken law function that you guided me to. Its not getting all four arguments that it required. Im editing my question to show the new code. Could you please comment what might be going wrong?

Comment: you provided me with the function definition for the broken power law only, which I used with the code that I already have. I guess the code that I have, doesn't work properly. Im looking at it at the moment, but the issue is that Im a bit pressed on time. So if you could help, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Do the following to define your function, and it will solve. x is an array (or list) and it should return y as an array (or list). And then you can use it in curvefit.

```
def fit_function(x, a1, a2, xc):
    y = []
    for xx in x:
        if xx<xc:
            y.append(x**a1)
        elif xx>xc:
            y.append(x**(a1 - a2) * x**a2)
        else:
            y.append(0.0)
    return y
```